# Unable to execute GAS code on localhost even though I add oauthscope

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run GAS on localhost
I setup clasp and could login correctly.

But when I execute `clasp run`, the following error occurs.

```
Exception: Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request [
```

I added oauthScopes to my manifest, but it doesn't still work.
Does anyone know why ??

This is my manifest.

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "dependencies": {},
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "executionApi": {
    "access": "DOMAIN"
  }
}
```

I use docker, but I don't think it is not problem

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I'm not sure about your script and your actual environment from your question, in your situation, when the property of `oauthScopes` is deleted and test it again, what result will you obtain? But if this was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to run GAS on localhost`? Do you mean *on* or *from*?

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly the problem you're having. Some of the comments above mentioned what GAS is referring to and it's referring to Google Appscript which is what clasp is geared toward.

What worked for me was getting the oauthScopes in the place you define and I think you may need to get that specific scope in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project= where the project= is the project number that your api for this is associated with. From here you just edit the app in the oauth consent screen and go to the second step and paste https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request into the manual area whenever you add a scope.

After you have all of this and saved you will need to do `clasp login --creds creds.json` for it all to take effect it seems. Just make sure you have ALL of your scopes in appscript.json or you'll still have trouble. If you find another one having a problem, make sure you go back into the oauth consent and add whatever scopes are broken. And anytime you modify a scope, login with `clasp login --creds creds.json` again.